# TextVectorization issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Im tryng to use TextVectorization on my model but im getting the same error, i tried creating an explicit input layer of 1 but its not working. Any advice?

```
vectorize_layer  = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens = 30000,output_mode = 'tf_idf',ngrams = 2,)
vectorize_layer.adapt(X_train)
X_train_vec = vectorize_layer(X_train).numpy()
X_test_vec = vectorize_layer(X_test).numpy()
X_valid_vec = vectorize_layer(X_valid).numpy()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
model.add(vectorize_layer)model.add(Dense(256,activation = 'relu', input_shape = (X_train_vec.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))model.add(Dense(128,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))model.add(Dense(4,activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adamax', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()

callbacks = [keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("model.keras",save_best_only = True),]

model.fit(X_train_vec, y_train,epochs = 15,batch_size = 32,validation_data = (X_valid_vec, y_valid),callbacks = callbacks)

model = keras.models.load_model('model.keras')
```

The error i got:

`When usingTextVectorizationto tokenize strings, the input rank must be 1 or the last shape dimension must be 1. Received: inputs.shape=(None, 18418) with rank=2`

I tried creating an explicit input layer of shape 1, but i keep getting the same .

Comment: Hi there! Would you mind providing some example data so that we can run your code snippet?

Comment: Hi @SimonDavid Thanks for your time. Here is example data https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spbilbao/PublicData/main/example.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [tensorflow documentation on text classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification), I modified your code and applied `TextVectorization` as a preprocessing step, where the vectorized text is passed to the model together with the label. Below is a fully working code snippet using a subset of the data you provided in your comment:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

# generating some data
X_train = [
    ("Les faltan sucursales, han cerrado muchas, sobretodo en Providencia y eso complica la operativa diaria.", "Sugerencia"),
    ("La nueva ejecutiva que me asignaron, es pésima, no responde los correos y ni siquiera hace contacto cada cierto tiempo. Realmente cambiaron a un excelente ejecutivo que tenia por otro que realmente deja harto que desear.", "Problema"),
    ("Excelente ejecutivo, proactivo, muy preocupado.", "Comentario Positivo"),
    ("siempre buena disposicion","Comentario Positivo"),
    ("La ejecutiva siempre contesta, aunque sea por malas notcias para el cliente, pero siempre está.", "Problema"),
    ("Atención personalizada y reservada, pocos tiempos de espera", "Comentario Positivo"),
    ("Personalmente bastante conforme, el problema es con el trato hacia mis esposa, obtuvimos las cuentas juntos, yo siendo su aval para tener los mismos productos. Y el servicio hacia ella, ha sido, cuando menos, deficiente, estuvo cerca de 6 meses sin ejecutivo asignado y la única vez que necesito ayuda del banco, se le indicó que al no contar con ejecutivo asignado, nadie era 100% responsable de su atención.", "Otros")
]

label_mapping = {
    "Otros": 0,
    "Problema": 1,
    "Comentario Positivo": 2,
    "Sugerencia": 3
}

train_df = pd.DataFrame(data=X_train, columns=['text', 'label'])
train_df['label'] = train_df['label'].map(label_mapping).astype(int)
# using the same data for the sake of simplicity
test_df = train_df.copy(deep=True)
valid_df = train_df.copy(deep=True)

# convert pandas dataframe to tensorflow dataset
raw_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(train_df))
raw_test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(test_df))
raw_val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(valid_df))

# fit text vectorization
vectorize_layer  = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=30000,
    output_mode='tf_idf',
    ngrams=2,
    pad_to_max_tokens=True)
vectorize_layer.adapt(raw_train_ds.map(lambda x: x['text']))

cat_encoding = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(
        num_tokens=4, output_mode='one_hot', sparse=False
)


def vectorize_text(row):
    text = tf.expand_dims(row['text'], -1)
    encoded_label = cat_encoding(row['label'])
    return vectorize_layer(text), tf.reshape(encoded_label, (1,4))


# apply text vectorization
train_ds = raw_train_ds.map(vectorize_text)
test_ds = raw_test_ds.map(vectorize_text)
val_ds = raw_val_ds.map(vectorize_text)

# define model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(30000,)))
model.add(Dense(256,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4,activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adamax', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()

callbacks = [keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("model.keras",save_best_only = True),]

# fit
model.fit(train_ds,epochs = 15,batch_size = 32,validation_data=val_ds, callbacks = callbacks)

model = keras.models.load_model('model.keras')
```